# Is there any other way than modifing DB Table in Solr Delta Imports?

Tags: solr

I need to do delta-import in Solr, but don't want to change underlying Database structure.

So, my question is, Is Solr have the enough intelligence to detect modified data itself and rebuild instead of telling that using `delta-query` and `delta-import-query`?? (`cons. : Time consuming??`)

Comment: how can solr have such intelligence ? if there is a way to detect deltas you should express that in your import sql :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes solr has this capability, just use the ${dataimporter.last_index_time} variable in your query and solr will only update recently modified data

Comment: Do you mean this http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerDeltaQueryViaFullImport ? if so, this is not what I mean! What I want to do is `don't want to change underlying Database structure`

Comment: Oh i see, well in that case, you can either add the new structure to the solr schema or you can use dynamic field declarations. Is this what you are looking for or did i misunderstand something?

Comment: Can you provide me with more details?